# Creating dynamic getters and setters from a base object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

This is my base object:

```
let resources = {
    TEST_FLAG: false,
    FRUIT: 'banana',
    ID: 11
};
```

I would like to access each property of that object through a `setter` and a `getter`. I attempt to do that below:

```
let dynamicResources = resources

for (let key in resources) {
    Object.defineProperty(dynamicResources, key, {
        get() {
            console.log(`[debug]: GET <${key}>, VALUE <${this[key]}>`);
            return `${this[key]}`;
        },

        set(value) {
            console.log(`[debug]: SET <${key}>, VALUE <${this[key]}>`);
            this[key] = value;
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is that the `getter` and `setter` can be generated from a base object with arbitrary number of properties.

When I `console.log()` the resulting object I get this:

```
{
  TEST_FLAG: [Getter/Setter],
  FRUIT: [Getter/Setter],
  ID: [Getter/Setter]
}
```

Which is an indication that the factory loop has worked. However, when I do this:

```
dynamicResources.FRUIT = 'berry';
```

I get the following error:

```
  set: function set(value) {
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

which is an indication that the nested functions are somewhat malformed.

How can I generate a dynamic getter/setter object based on a generic base object?

Comment: You got an infinite recursion, the `this[key] = value` statement from the setter calls the setter function again. To fix that, store and retrieve the value to/from a different property.

Comment: As @Titus said you're not really grasping the concept of getters and setters in JS. You need a separate property that contains the value. All getters and setters are just proxies.

Comment: Can you tell us what your ultimate goal is? It can't be creating console logs, right? Maybe there's a different way to reach that goal.

Comment: The goal is to be able to set and get values using just property names, such as `foo.ID = 33`, `foo.FRUIT = 'orange'`, `foo.TEST_FLAG = false`.

Comment: But instead of manually defining the individual `setter` and `getter` access points, I would like to generate them with a factory function. So if there are other properties, those will have `setter` and `getter` functionality as well.

Comment: You can get and set an object's properties' values like that without getters and setters.

Comment: Yes, but if I would like to sanitize (or run any kind of an operation) before setting and retrieving the values I need this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Proxy** constructor. Look to  [Developer Mozilla Proxy Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```js
var dynamicObject = new Proxy({
   TEST_FLAG: false,
   FRUIT: 'banana',
   ID: 11
  },{
  get:function(target,key){
   console.log(`get ${key} value. value is: ${target[key]}`);
   return target[key]
  },
  set:function(target,key,val){
    console.log(`set ${key} value. old value is:${target[key]} new value is ${val}`)
    target[key] = val;
    return true;
  }
})

console.log(dynamicObject.ID);
dynamicObject.ID = 25;




// Output is:
/*
get ID value. value is: 11
11
set ID value. old value is:11 new value is 25
*/
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a method inside the Proxy, a method that is also will be callable, for example: `dynamicResources.lock(true)`?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```js
let resources = {
    TEST_FLAG: false,
    FRUIT: 'banana',
    ID: 11
};

let dynamicResources = {
    _state: {...resources}
}

for (let key in resources) {
    Object.defineProperty(dynamicResources, key, {
        get() {
            const internalKey = key
            return this._state[internalKey]
        },
        set(value) {
            const internalKey = key
            this._state[internalKey] = value;
        }
    });
}
console.log(dynamicResources.FRUIT)
dynamicResources.FRUIT = 'berry';
console.log(dynamicResources.FRUIT)
```